# $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]$ with $Z=X-Y$

Tags: probability

If $X\perp Y\sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$ and $Z=2X-Y$, how can I compute $\mathbb{E}[|2X-Y|]$?

Generally speaking, what is $\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|]$ and $\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]$?

In our case, knowing that $X\in [0,+\infty)$, is it correct saying that $\mathbb{E}[|2X-Y|]\leq |2|\mathbb{E}[|X|]+|-1|\mathbb{E}[|Y|]$ where $\mathbb{E}[|X|]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}|x|f_X(x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}xf_X(x)=\Gamma(2)=1=\mathbb{E}[|Y|]\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[|Z|]\leq 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joint density is given by $f_{X,Y} (x,y)=e^{-x}e^{-y}$ for $0<x,y <\infty$. Hence $E|2X-Y|=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2x} (2x-y) e^{-x}e^{-y}dydx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{2x}^{\infty} (y-2x) e^{-x}e^{-y}dydx$. I will let you carry out the integration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So $\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=\frac{5}{3}>\mathbb{E}[Z]=1$.